# What is better yaml configuration loading practise?

Tags: python, configuration, yaml

**Hello,**

I am working on a small project where I use yaml configuration file. Recently I wondered what practise is better (making code more readable, expandable and maintenaceable) among (1) loading previously initialized config dict directly into modules, (2) passing config values as arguments or (3) some other way.

**Sample code:**

config.yml:

```
my_foo: foo
my_bar: bar
```

**Case (1):**

my_config.py:

```
import yaml

with open(config.yaml, "r") as stream:
    try:
        my_config = yaml.safe_load(stream)
    except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
        print(exc)
```

my_foo.py:

```
from my_config import my_config

class MyFoo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = my_config[my_foo]
```

my_bar.py:

```
from my_config import my_config

class MyBar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = my_config[my_bar]
```

my_main.py:

```
from my_foo import MyFoo
from my_bar import MyBar

my_foo_instance = MyFoo()
my_bar_instance = MyBar()
```

**Case (2):**

my_foo.py:

```
class MyFoo:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
```

my_bar.py:

```
class MyBar:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
```

my_main.py:

```
from my_foo import MyFoo
from my_bar import MyBar

with open(config.yaml, "r") as stream:
    try:
        my_config = yaml.safe_load(stream)
    except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
        print(exc)

my_foo_instance = MyFoo(val=my_config[my_foo])
my_bar_instance = MyBar(val=my_config[my_bar])
```

Comment: Is the config a config file for the whole project or only for `MyClass`? In the latter case I would create a classmethod that loads your config file into the class context.

Comment: I use one config file for the whole project.  I edited question to better reflect my case.

Comment: why do you have two classes that would be populated from the same config file? I think you might need to elaborate on your use case a bit more. As it is, is hard to determine the use of a `MyFoo.val` attribute, for example; depending on that, a YAML config file might not be needed after all.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest an improvement on your first case, which I think is better than your second case.

config.py:

```
import yaml

def load_config(path):
    with open(path, "r") as stream:
        # I'm leaving the try-except out because normally 
        # you want your program to fail if the config is incorrect!
        my_config = yaml.safe_load(stream)
    return my_config
```

main.py:

```
from my_foo import MyFoo
from my_bar import MyBar
from config import load_config

# Giving the path here is more flexible, you will 
# be able to pass a path as an argument to your program for example
my_config = load_config("my/path.yaml")

my_foo_instance = MyFoo(val=my_config[my_foo])
my_bar_instance = MyBar(val=my_config[my_bar])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I see how your improved version is better then sample code provided in the question. However, my concern focuses on differences between  importing config into classes and passing values as arguments. Could you provide your rationale for passing config values as arguments?

Comment: This is a bit project dependent, some small projects, projects that perform exactly one action for example, might want to share all configuration across functions/classes. But, if we look at popular workflow frameworks like airflow and dagster, you will see that each component (or class in your case) has configuration specified specifically for it. This is normally guided by the idea that one action doesn't have to know anything about the other action to function, they only rely on well defined inputs and outputs.

Comment: So in practice these frameworks use a configuration file format that has separate fields for each component, like in my answer, where the `my_foo` field contains configuration only for `MyFoo`.